# Frequently used site not showing in frequent sites on sharepoint home screen

Tags: sharepoint-online

we have a site that many users use everyday but it never shows up in frequent sites. Also doesn't show near top on followed sites.

Did I make a change in a setting that keeps it from showing?

Sorry this seems like it would be something easy to fix but after multiple google searches couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is not feasible to customize the SharePoint landing page in Office 365.

There are many complaints about the nonsensical sharepoint.aspx page and currently Microsoft is taking time to fix these problem.

I suggest you submit your feedback via SharePoint Online Uservoice. It will let our related team hear your voice. Many good features are added from customers' good suggestions.

SharePoint User voice:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/

As a workaround, you can add this site to your favorites, and then you can access it quickly. Or you can add this site in the "Featured links" in the SharePoint home page.

[image]

Comment: We removed the default group created when we set up our site. I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of "Following" sites appear in descending order from when you starting following them (i.e., the site you've followed most recently will appear at the top of the list). Since MS hasn't given us the functionality to re-order the list, I sometimes unfollow/re-follow the site(s) I want to appear at the top of my list.